# How to convert a char array into string based hex-stream (ostringstream)

Tags: c++, string, hex, ostringstream

in C++ (on Linux with gcc) I'd like to put a byte array (`vector<unsigned char>`) to a `ostringstream` or a `string`.

I know that I can use `sprintf` but it doesn't seem to be the best way to use `char*` also.

btw: [this link did not help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362797/converting-a-char-array-to-something-that-can-be-appended-to-a-ostringstream)

**Edit:** All answer work so far. But I did not meantion, that I'd like to convert the bytes/hex-values into their string representation, e.g., `vector<..> = {0,1,2} -> string = "000102"`. Sorry for that missing but important detail

Comment: if you want to perform decimal to string conversion with leading zero, sprintf is the easiest way.  You can also use boost::lexical_cast

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Little chance of getting an up-vote, but since it is *exactly* what the OP asked for, and no other answer, including the selected one, oddly, does so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

// used by bin2hex for conversion via stream.
struct bin2hex_str
{
    std::ostream& os;
    bin2hex_str(std::ostream& os) : os(os) {}
    void operator ()(unsigned char ch)
    {
        os << std::hex
        << std::setw(2)
        << static_cast<int>(ch);
    }
};

// convert a vector of unsigned char to a hex string
std::string bin2hex(const std::vector<unsigned char>& bin)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::setfill('0');
    std::for_each(bin.begin(), bin.end(), bin2hex_str(oss));
    return oss.str();
}

// or for those who wish for a C++11-compliant version
std::string bin2hex11(const std::vector<unsigned char>& bin)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::setfill('0');
    std::for_each(bin.begin(), bin.end(),
        [&oss](unsigned char ch)
        {
            oss << std::hex
            << std::setw(2)
            << static_cast<int>(ch);
        });
    return oss.str();
}
```

---

**Alternate Stream Dump**

If all you want to do is dump an unsigned char fixed array the following will *handily* do so, which almost no overhead at all.

```
template<size_t N>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const unsigned char (&ar)[N])
{
    static const char alpha[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    for (size_t i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        os.put(alpha[ (ar[i]>>4) & 0xF ]);
        os.put(alpha[ ar[i] & 0xF ]);
    }
    return os;
}
```

I use this all the time when I want to dump fixed buffers to an ostream derivitive. The call is dead-simple:

```
unsigned char data[64];
...fill data[] with, well.. data...
cout << data << endl;
```

Comment: @tuergeist I just noticed the question. What I don't understand is why the accepted answer is just that; accepted? You specifically wanted  the *bytes* in your vector converted to their 2-char asci string representation. I.e. `{0x1F, 0x2E, 0x3D}` becomes `"1F2E3D"`. All the accepted answer does is copy *characters* from a vector to a string. Odd. Thanks for the up-vote, btw.

Comment: fixed ;) - months ago that was the best answer

Comment: @tuergeist ok. I didn't mean for you to change your selection. I just thought it unusual. Perhaps the question conditions changed since it was posted and selected. No worries. I'm glad you have a working solution. The stream dump method at the bottom of this answer is one I use frequently. It takes very little effort to xmorph it into a vector-based solution as well.

Answer (score 8):

From vector char arr to stl string:

```
std::string str(v.begin(), v.end());
```

From stl string to vector char array:

```
std::string str = "Hellow World!";
std::vector<unsigned char> v(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Comment: Are you talking about this? for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) { str+= v[i]; }

Comment: As YeenFei pointed out, if you want a leading zero, probably you can use sprintf...

Answer (score 3):

For setw include:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

This should put 01 in stream:

```
std::ostringstream oss;

unsigned char byte = 0x01;
oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(byte);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **[boost::alogorithm::hex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/the_boost_algorithm_library/Misc/hex.html)**

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
```

For std::ostream

```
std::ostream ss;
boost::algorithm::hex(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(ss));
```

For std::string

```
std::string res;
boost::algorithm::hex(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to put the data of a vector of chars into a string? Easy:

```
string str;
str.resize(vec.size());
for (int n=0;n<vec.size();n++) {
  str[n] = vec[n];
}
```

Comment: why are you using stl string without utilizing other stl features? (for_each, iterator, etc)